# Deserializing enum from the Serializationinfo store?

Tags: c#, serialization, enums

I have a class called `UnitsManager`. In this class is an enum:

```
public enum TimeUnit
{
    Seconds,
    Milliseconds,
    Minutes,
    Hours,
    Days,
    Months,
    Years
}
```

This enum is used in another class called `Process`. It has a property:

```
    private TimeUnit cycleTimeUnit = TimeUnit.Seconds; 
    [XmlAttribute("CycleTimeUnit")]
    public TimeUnit CycleTimeUnit
    {
        get { return this.cycleTimeUnit; }
        set { this.cycleTimeUnit = value; }
    }
```

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize the `Process` class. I've implemented ISerializable on the `Process` class

```
    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);

        info.AddValue("CycleTime", CycleTime);
        info.AddValue("CycleTimeUnit", CycleTimeUnit);
    }
```

My problem comes in the deserialization

```
    private Process(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        CycleTime = info.GetDouble("CycleTime");
        CycleTimeUnit = info.????("CycleTimeUnit"); // <--- ???
    }
```

How do I cast this as a type `CycleTimeUnit`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
private Process(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    CycleTime = info.GetDouble("CycleTime");
    CycleTimeUnit = (TimeUnit) info.GetValue("CycleTimeUnit", typeof(TimeUnit)); 
}
```

Comment: Almost! `CycleTimeUnit = (TimeUnit)info.GetValue("CycleTimeUnit", typeof(TimeUnit));` did the trick! Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, I edited to give the right answer for the future.